# About "residual" scalar curvature in Einstein warped product manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensor, ricci-curvature

I have an Einstein warped product manifold $M=B \times_f F$ with warped metric $g=g^B+f^2g^F$, where $F$ is Ricci flat, then its scalar curvature is $S^F=0$.

It is well known that the scalar curvature of $M$ is:

$S(p,q)=S^{B}(p,q)+\frac{S^{F}}{f^{2}}-2n\frac{\Delta f}{f}-n(n-1)\frac{\langle\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle}{f^{2}}$, where $p$ are points on $B$ and $q$ are point on $F$.

Since $S^F=0$, it becomes:
$S(p,q)=S^{B}(p,q)-2n\frac{\Delta f}{f}-n(n-1)\frac{\langle\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle}{f^{2}}$.

Then the term $S^B$ is scalar curvature of $B$ and $S^F=0$.

If I subtract from $S(p,q)$ the scalar curvature of $B$, I obtain the following:

$S(p,q)-S^{B}(p,q) =-2n\frac{\Delta f}{f}-n(n-1)\frac{\langle\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle}{f^{2}}$, which is a sort of "residue" of scalar curvature of $M$ subtracted $S^B$.

Since $S^F=0$, then $g^F$ is a Ricci flat metric, so how is it possible to decompose the "residual" curvature in order to show what depends on $g^B$ and what on $f^2g^F$?

Comment: Could you make your question more precise, please? In view of the formulas given above, it is obvious that the "residual" scalar curvature only depends on \nabla\log f and g^B. A reference that contains most of the relevant formulas for this setting is Besse's book on Einstein manifolds. But as this chapter on Riemannian submersion treats so general situations, it requires some effort to understand all the formulas in there.

Comment: @Bernd Ammann - thanks so much for the suggestion I mean that residue depends on the metric of M i.e. $g^B+f^2g^F$. I would like to understand if it is possible to "break it down" to rewrite it in terms dependent only on $g^B$ and terms dependent only on $f^g^F$.

Comment: You asked whether the "residue depends [only] on the metric of $M$ i.e. $g^B+f^2g^F$", i.e. you asked whether it only depends on the Riemannian metric on $M$, didn't you? If yes, then the answer is obviously "No", as it also depends on how you choose the product structure $M=B\times F$ (as smooth manifolds).

Comment: But maybe you consider this as given as well. Then your formula with $\Delta  f$ and $\nabla f$ gives you what one can say, and I do not see any more what you are asking. Also this formula just requires $S^F=0$ and not ricci-flatness. When you write "Since $S^F=0$, then $g^F$ is a Ricci flat metric", then your implication goes in the wrong direction: since $g^F$ is ricci-flat, you have $S^F=0$.

Comment: @Bernd Ammann - Thanks for the answers.
Yes $S^F=0$, while $S^B$ is different from zero. Since $S^M-S^B$ provides terms that are not necessarily zero, I was wondering if these terms ($-2n\frac{\Delta f}{f}$ and $-n(n-1)\frac{\langle \nabla f,\nabla f\rangle}{f^{2}}$) could be expressed based on the metrics involved.
For example, the second fundamental form of $F$ is $-\frac{\langle U, V \rangle}{f} \nabla f$, and it is obtained solely from the metric $f^2g^F$. Similarly, I was wondering if we could rewrite the residual terms by diversifying what is obtained from $f^2g^F$ and what from $g^B$.

Comment: In your case, it is pretty clear that nothing depends on $g^F$: as long as $g^F$ is scalar flat it makes zero contribution to the scalar curvature of the warped product, and you can freely swap the fiber out with any other scalar flat manifold. // You also make some really strange notational choices. For example, I don't see why you write $S^B(p,q)$ when it is only a function of $p$. I also don't see why you insist on grouping "$f^2 g^F$" as one object. It is better to think of $g^F$ as a tensor field on the fiber $F$ and $f^2$ as a scalar field on the base $B$, so you have 3 objects in play.

Comment: In terms of references: There's a section in O'Neill's Semi-Riemannian Manifolds dedicated to Warped Products;  I think it is a bit easier to digest than Besse.

Comment: @Willie Wong - thank you very much for your suggestions! I insist with $f^2g^F$ because the warped metric is $g^B+f^2g^F$.Since we are dealing with a warped-product manifold, for example, the following scalar product: $\langle U,V \rangle_{(p,q)}$, where $U, V$ are lifts on $F$ to $B \times F$, and $p,q$ are points on $B$ and $F$ respectively, then it will be: $f^2(p)\langle U_q,V_q\rangle$, so the metric involved is $f^2g^F$.

Comment: It's not possible to separate those terms into a base contribution and a fibre contribution. They can be written as a linear combination (constant coefficients) of ${\rm div}_{g^B}(H)$ and $\Vert H \Vert_{g^B}^2$, where $H$ is the mean curvature vector of the fibres, which can be identified with the vector field $-n \nabla \log f$ on $B$. 

Notice that $H$ depends both on $f$ (obviously), but also on $g^B$, since the gradient is taken with respect to $g^B$. The same is true for the divergence term (ok, you could argue that this only depends on the volume form associated to $g^B$).

Comment: Thank you very much!